# Pandas: Fill rows if 2 column strings are the same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set with ton of columns, I just want to back fill the rows that are missing with existing row values. I am trying to back fill with this logic like: if 'school' and 'country' are the same string then replace 'state' value into the empty 'state' column.

Here is an example. Problem with this is that its combining the other rows I am trying not split the rows. Is there a way? Thanks!

Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
school = ['Univ of CT','Univ of CT','Oxford','Oxford','ABC Univ']
name = ['John','Matt','John','Ashley','John']
country = ['US','US','UK','UK','']
state = ['CT','','','ENG','']
df = pd.DataFrame({'school':school,'country':country,'state':state,'name':name})
df['school'] = df['school'].str.upper()
```

Above data gives preview like:

```
school      country state   name
UNIV OF CT  US      CT     John
UNIV OF CT  US             Matt
OXFORD      UK             John
OXFORD      UK      ENG    Ashley
ABC UNIV                   John
```

I am looking for output like this:

```
school      country state   name
UNIV OF CT  US      CT     John
UNIV OF CT  US      CT     Matt
OXFORD      UK      ENG    John
OXFORD      UK      ENG    Ashley
ABC UNIV                   John
```

Code I tried:

```
df = df.fillna('')
df = df.reset_index().groupby(['school','country']).agg(';'.join) 
df = pd.DataFrame(df).reset_index()
len(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a small function to basically look up the state if it is blank based on the school and country.

```
def find_state(school, country, state):
    if len(state) > 0:
        return state
    found_state = df['state'][(df['school'] == school) & (df['country'] == country)]
    return max(found_state)
```

So the full example would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
school = ['Univ of CT','Univ of CT','Oxford','Oxford','ABC Univ']
name = ['John','Matt','John','Ashley','John']
country = ['US','US','UK','UK','']
state = ['CT','','','ENG','']
df = pd.DataFrame({'school':school,'country':country,'state':state,'name':name})
df['school'] = df['school'].str.upper()

def find_state(school, country, state):
    if len(state) > 0:
        return state
    found_state = df['state'][(df['school'] == school) & (df['country'] == country)]
    return max(found_state)

df['state_new'] = [find_state(school, country, state) for school, country, state in 
                   df[['school','country','state']].values]
print(df)

    school       country  state  name     state_new
0   UNIV OF CT    US       CT    John     CT
1   UNIV OF CT    US             Matt     CT
2   OXFORD        UK             John     ENG
3   OXFORD        UK       ENG   Ashley   ENG
4   ABC UNIV                     John
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

first try to convert empty space to nan and then simply use `ffill()` and `bfill()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'school':school,'country':country,'state':state,'name':name})
df['school'] = df['school'].str.upper()

df['state'] = df['state'].astype(str).replace('',np.nan)
df['state'] = df.groupby(['school', 'country'])['state'].transform(lambda x: x.ffill()).transform(lambda y: y.bfill())
print(df)

    school country state    name
UNIV OF CT      US    CT    John
UNIV OF CT      US    CT    Matt
    OXFORD      UK   ENG    John
    OXFORD      UK   ENG  Ashley
  ABC UNIV           NaN    John
```

Comment: I dont think this works as expected if the input data is changed slightly.  Use this on `school = ['Univ of CT','Univ of CT','Oxford','Oxford','ABC Univ','Univ of CT']
name = ['John','Matt','John','Ashley','John','mark']
country = ['US','US','UK','UK','','US']
state = ['CT','','','ENG','','']` and you get `CT` filled in for `ABC Univ`